# Intersection multiplicity of two curves

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

The definition of the local ring at one point $P$ is given by $$O_p=\{ \frac{f}{g}:f,g \in K[x,y]:g(P)\neq0 \}\subset K(x,y)$$
It admits a well-defined ring homomorphism: $$O_p \to K,\frac{f}{g}\longmapsto \frac{f(P)}{g(P)}$$ which we call the evaluation map. Its kernel will be denoted by $$I_P=\{ \frac{f}{g}:f,g \in K[x,y]:f(P)=0, g(P)\neq0 \}$$
The definition of intersection multiplicity of two curves defined by two polynomials $F$ and $G$ at one point $P$ is given by: $$\mu_P=dimO_p/(F,G)$$ where $dim$ denotes the dimension as a vector space over $K$.
Let's suppose that point $f(P)=G(P)=0$.

My books says:

The evaluation map at $P$ induces a well-defined and surjective map $$O_P/(F,G)\longmapsto K$$

Question 1: This is clear, since the evaluation map is surjective, right?.

It follows that $$\mu_P(F,G)\geq1$$

Question2: This is also clear since the map is surjective and $dimK$ is always greater than $1$, right?.

Now, my biggest doubt. My book says:

$\mu_P(F,G)=1$ if and only if this map is an isomorphism, that means, if and only if $(F,G)$ is exactly the kernel $I_P$ of the evaluation map.

Question 3: I am not able to see this whatsoever. I have tried to apply the First Isomorphic Theorem, different calculations using the kernel.......

Why does the map $O_P/(F,G)\longmapsto K$ being a isomorphism make the dimension to be $1$?

Kisses.

Comment: Rank-nullity formula?

Comment: Hello Angina Seng. How can I apply the Rank-nullity formula?. I mean, I do not know neither the dimension of $K$ nor the dimension of the kernel, even the dimension of $O_P$. Please, could you be more specific?.
Kisses.

Comment: I do think that perhaps $K$ has dimension one, as a $K$-vector space.

Comment: Hello Angina Seng. I think that you are right, any field $K$ is a vector space over itself of dimension $1$. If so, I understand now the demonstration.
Thank you so much Angina Seng.
Kisses.

Comment: Is $K$ algebraically closed?

Comment: Hello Youngsu. Yes, the field $K$ is algebraically closed.
Since a field $K$ has always dimension $1$ as vector space over itself, and two vector spaces are isomorphic if and only if their dimensions are equals, applying the First Isomorphic Theorem, my problem is solved.
Thank you so much for the answer.
Kisses.